# Tampermonkeyでyoutubeのチャンネル名を取得する方法

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

#### 前提・実現したいこと

youtubeで特定のチャンネルだけ見れるようにしたく、Tampermonkey(Javascript)でyoutubeのチャンネル名を取得し、それがホワイトリストのものと適合しなかったらウインドウを閉じる(見えなくする)というコードを動かそうとしています。
tampermonkeyのコードが転がっていたので流用したかったのですが、正しく動きません。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

下記のコードで、

```
var testString = $(".yt-user-info")[0].firstElementChild.innerHTML;
```

が機能せず、そこでコードが止まってしまいます（特にエラーなどなし）

#### 該当のソースコード

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Youtube Whitelist Script
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1b
// @description  This script will remove the content from Youtube videos. Ignores whitelisted content
// @author       Louis Vaught
// @match        https://www.youtube.com/watch*
// @copyright    2017, Louis Vaught
// @require      https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js
// ==/UserScript==

var $ = window.jQuery;
///////////////////////
// EDIT WHITELIST HERE:
///////////////////////

var whitelist = [
'TheBackyardScientist',
'Cody\'sLab',
'The Slo Mo Guys'
];
//Make sure to match the name exactly. Not case-sensitive.

//////////////////////////
// String Search Function:
//////////////////////////

function searchStringInArray (str, strArray) {
for (var j=0; j<strArray.length; j++) {
var testStr = strArray[j].toLowerCase();
var matchStr = str.toLowerCase();
if (testStr.match(matchStr)) return j;
}
return -1;
}

////////////////////
// Main Script Body:
////////////////////

$(document).ready(function() {
alert("main kokokara")
//Find the channel name on the page
var testString = $(".yt-user-info")[0].firstElementChild.innerHTML;
//    var testString ="hogehoge"
alert(testString)
//Search for the channel name in the array
var searchVal = searchStringInArray(testString,whitelist);
//If the channel isn't present, then delete content and error out:
if (searchVal==-1) {
$("#page-container").remove();
alert("This channel isn't on the Youtube whitelist!");
}
});
```

#### 試したこと

コードの上部で

```
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js
var $ = window.jQuery;
```

と指定しているのでjQueryは使えると思うんですが、(エラーはでない)
実際には使えていないのかもしれません。

コードの間違い、もしくはjQueryの使い方の間違いなどがありましたらご指摘いただけますと嬉しいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿をされているようですが [teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/320591), [Yahoo!知恵袋](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14238318909)、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Answer (score 0):

マルチポストである旨、記載せず申し訳ありません。
下記サイトにて解決いたしました。
https://teratail.com/questions/320591#